# Show that $f$ is integrable and $\int_{[0,1] \times[0,1]} f=1 / 2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> - $ EXERCISE  .$ Let $f:[0,1] \times[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
>     $$
>   f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
>   {0} & {\text { if } 0 \leqslant x<1 / 2} \\
>   {1} & {\text { if } 1 / 2 \leqslant x \leqslant 1}
>   \end{array}\right.
>   $$
>     Show that $f$ is integrable and $\int_{[0,1] \times[0,1]} f=1 / 2.$

My attempt. Let $P$ a partition of $[0,1] \times[0,1].$ Let $S_1=[0,1/2)$ and $S_2=[1/2,1]$ be subrectangles of $P$.

Note that $m_{S_1}(f)=0$ and $m_{S_2}(f)=1$, I think, I made a mistake. I'm confused. Could you help me,please, can you add an answer? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

$\iint_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}\;f(x,y)\; dxdy=\iint_{R_1}\;f(x,y)\;dxdy + \iint_{R_2}\;f(x,y)\;dxdy = 0+\iint_{R_2} 1\;dxdy=\text{Area}(R_2)=\frac{1}{2}$

where the rectangles $R_1=[0,\frac{1}{2})\times [0,1], R_2=[\frac{1}{2},1]\times [0,1]$ together partition $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.